# Stop Adobe Elements Auto Creations 2023 from running altogether

Tags: adobe, adobe-photoshop

I installed Adobe Photoshop Elements 2023, which annoyingly comes with a load of useless crud I do not want, but seems so interconnected I cannot just remove it.  One of this useless (to me) pieces of software is Adobe Elements 2023 Organizer, which seems to run some sort of useless 'auto creation' (of what?!?) in the background.  I ticked all the boxes in the damn app preferences to stop it from doing so, but it still does.  I also disabled Adobe from running automatically in the System Setting to no avail.

So the questions:

1. can I altogether remove Adobe Elements 2023 Organizer without stopping Photoshop Elements from working?
2. if no, can I at least totally disable  Auto Creations from running in the background?

I am on Ventura, on a M1.

Comment: If my post comes across as frustrated, it is because I am.

Comment: Is Organizer a separate app, listed in /Applications? If so, then you should be able to delete it. And you can always delete anything, if you have a backup to restore it, if it doesn't work.

Comment: it is a separate app, but they might share a number of components.  I can just re-download the installer, but it is a hassle I would rather avoid (it make testing different approaches to removing Organiser too time consuming).

Comment: Do a backup, delete the cr*p you don't want. Test. If it works fine, if not, restore from backup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can remove Adobe Elements 2023 Organizer without affecting the functionality of Adobe Photoshop Elements 2023. The Organizer is a separate program and is not necessary for Photoshop Elements to function properly.

To **remove Adobe Elements 2023 Organizer**, follow these steps:

1. Quit Adobe Photoshop Elements 2023 if it is running.
2. Open the Applications folder on your Mac.
3. Locate Adobe Elements 2023 Organizer and drag it to the Trash.
4. Empty the Trash.

After completing these steps, Adobe Elements 2023 Organizer should be completely removed from your system.

If you prefer **not to remove the Organizer**, you can disable Auto Creations from running in the background. To do this, follow these steps:

1. **Open** Adobe Elements 2023 Organizer.
2. Go to the **Edit menu** > **Preferences** > Auto Creations tab.
3. **Uncheck all the boxes** under **Enable Auto Creations**.
4. Click **OK** to **save the changes**.

This should disable Auto Creations from running in the background.

Note that disabling Auto Creations may affect certain features in [Adobe Photoshop Elements 2023](https://trustedbay.com/adobe-photoshop-elements-review/) that rely on it, such as the "Auto Creations" tab in the Home screen. If you experience any issues, you can always re-enable Auto Creations by following the same steps and checking the boxes under "Enable Auto Creations."

Comment: I have not found "Enable Auto Creations" in "preferences"